# imprimir numeros usando ToString em java

Tags: java

rabisco do  projeto mais ele não imprimi os números dentro do []...

```
package tostring2;

import java.util.Arrays;


public class ToString2 {

    public static String ToString2(int [] a) {

       int idades [] = {12,20,30,40};
       int i;

       for (i = 0; i < 4 ; i++){
          System.out.println(idades[i]);
       }
       for (i=0; i < idades.length;i++){
          System.out.println("idades "+Arrays.toString(idades));
       }
}
```

Comment: fui editar sua pergunta e percebi que faltava um fechar chave `}`. Não sei se seu fonte está assim, mas se estiver pode ser a causa do erro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você criou um método mas não o chamou.

Crie um método main e o chame dentro dele. Exemplo:

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    ToString2();
}
```

Veja funcionando no Ideone: http://ideone.com/M834OQ

Comment: Funcionou criando Método main...Obrigada pela ajuda!